# Add data to different tables in DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can you add data from client side forms to different tables in the DB?

My situation is this, I have three forms client side, the first is for books items (hardback,magazine etc), second one is for music items (cds,cassettes etc,), third is for movies items (dvds, VHS, etc.).

A user should be able to enter details in any of the forms, then the data should be populated in the correct table in the db.

Any ideas guys or scripts readily avail? I need it to be extensible so it should handle multiple requests without slowing down or causing to many errors (I don't mind debugging a few :) ). Ive also got to think about who posted what to make the system scalable.

Oh and am a front end designer not an exp core software application web programmer engineer coder.

Setup:
PHP
mySQL
JS
HTML

All help welcome.

I am Sorry guys! The current code is as follows for the books, its the same for music and movies:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('../config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$isbn = clean($_POST['isbn']);
$bookTitle = clean($_POST['bookTitle']);
    $author = clean($_POST['author']);  
$genre = clean($_POST['genre']);
$year= clean($_POST['year']);


//Input Validations
if($isbn == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'ISBN missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($bookTitle == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Book Title missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($author == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'author missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($genre == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Genre missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($year == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Year missing';
    $errflag = true;
}


//Check for duplicate login ID
if($isbn != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Book and ISBN ID already in system';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    die('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
    header("location: addMedia.php");
    exit();
}

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO books(isbn, title, author, genre, year) VALUES('$isbn','$bookTitle','$author','$genre','$year')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: bookAdded.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
} ?>
```

Comment: You can get which form is submitted from it's name (html form's name attribute), i.e. `if($_POST['booksForm']) { /* insert to books table */ } elseif($_POST['musicForm']) { /* insert to music table */ } elseif($_POST['moviesForm']) { /* insert to movies table */ }`. Do you have something to show?

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO. This site is generally meant for specific questions after you have tried several things and failed to solve a problem. It is also nice if you tell us what you have already tried. In this case I recommend you to read up on Web Development in general or hire a coder if it a commercial project.

Comment: It actually works, however the question should have been: I won't know which user added what, this will be confusing too when coming to displaying the results back client side for the current signed in user.

Comment: Because let's say for instance if a user called 'user A' posted books or one book (book 1), and then user B and user C signed in, they will see user A's books too! Basically it's a system design question??

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server-side script that will process your front-end forms.

Foreach form, you will insert in a different table using PDO extension from PHP, [read more about it here.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: It actually works, however the question should have been: I won't know which user added what, this will be confusing too when coming to displaying the results back client side for the current signed in user.

Comment: You should have a inserted_by field in each table. Then, you will just show the books that were inserted by the user (by using ie $_SESSION['user_id']).

Comment: I think that will not work if user is logged in but has no books.                               For example right now I have tried that method with this code,              `if($sql.bookID == ($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']));

$result = mysql_query($sql);
else
(

echo "You have no books added yet!";

)`

Comment: And didn't that code worked it out? If not, why not? Isn't it what are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I have a session issue. As it looks like me(or any other db user) have no rights to read (and write) the database? I do not know who in the world changed the rights when I manage the whole app and db. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried checking the permissions for the user you are using in cPanel (I guess you're on a server?)? And maybe adding a user with more permissions?

Comment: Have you found the answer? If mine is the correct or guided you through the right path, please mark it as correct and explain how did you achieved the answer :)

Comment: I am the super user with full admin rights in the DB. So it should work and everything should work if I want to do anything. Sorry this is an old thread Ivo.

Comment: Think of it like Facebook or any other basic social platform!